# Triviality of $\mathrm{Ann}(\mathfrak m)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

This question is regarding the first paragraph of the proof of Proposition 2.4 from [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0209199.pdf).

QUESTION: Is it true that if $(0)$ is irreducible, then $\mathrm{Soc}(R)=\mathrm{Ann}(\mathfrak m)=(0:_R\mathfrak m)$ is non-zero for a general commutative local ring $(R,\mathfrak m)$ which is not a domain?

The proof provided there in the first paragraph starts by assuming that $\dim(\mathrm{Soc}(R))\geq 2$ and gets a contradiction. But it could still be zero, in particular this proof does not work for arbitrary (non-noetherian) commutative ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R$ is a local integral domain which is not a field, then $(0)$ is irreducible and its socle is obviously $0$.

More general, we have

> If $R$ is an irreducible Noetherian ring then every element of $R$ is a non-zerodivisor or nilpotent.

Suppose $a\in R$ is not nilpotent, and let $\mathrm{Ann}_R(a^n)$ maximal among the ideals of this form. Then $\mathrm{Ann}_R(a^{2n})=\mathrm{Ann}_R(a^n)$. Suppose $ab=0$, and $b\ne0$. We have $Ra^n\cap Rb\ne0$ (here one uses that $R$ is irreducible). Let $c\ne0$, $c\in Ra^n\cap Rb$. Write $c=ra^n$. Since $c\in Rb$ and $a^nb=0$ we get $ca^n=0$, so $ra^{2n}=0$. Then $ra^{n}=0$, that is, $c=0$, a contradiction.

We conclude:

> If $R$ is an irreducible Noetherian local ring then $\mathrm{Soc}(R)=0$ unless $R$ is Artinian.

If $R$ is an irreducible Noetherian local ring, and $\mathrm{Soc}(R)\ne0$ we get that all elements of $\mathfrak m$ are zerodivisors. By the result above all elements of $\mathfrak m$ are necessarily nilpotent, so $\mathfrak m$ is nilpotent. This shows that $R$ is Artinian.

Comment: Great. This is very nice.

Comment: do you think your result above is true for non-noetherian rings: that every element is a nzd or nilpotent. I feel it might be, but we cant use zorn's lemma argument in absence of ascending chain condition, which is what you cleverly used.

Answer (score 1):

It is obviously not $0$ because an Artinian ring always has nonzero socle.

A commutative ring with socle zero cannot have any minimal ideals.

Comment: My question is about any commutative ring in general, not necessarily an artinian ring.

Comment: I believe you are using the fact that the socle is the sum of all non-zero minimal ideals? So if Socle is zero, there are no minimal ideals? So what kind of commutative rings are these?

Comment: I mean examples among non-noetherian commutative rings.

Comment: @user114539 sorry, I did not notice that this article is using quite a bizarre definition of the socle. I guess it should still coincide with the standard definition though.

Comment: @rschwieb The use of socle in commutative algebra matches perfectly the non-commutative concept of socle. (I think I've seen this as a question on M.SE and I won't be surprised if your are the answerer.) Let me recall that for a module $M$ over a local ring the socle of $M$ is the annihilator of $\mathfrak m$ in $M$. Isn't this the sum of simple submodules of $M$?

Comment: @user26857 the thing is that the definition as the annihilator does not match the definition as the sum of simple submodules always. I'm pretty sure they can be unequal in general. What j really mean is I don't recognize the definition given in the specified article as "largest subspace with vector space structure"

Comment: Well, I think the author meant "with $(R/\mathfrak m)$-vector space structure". (I don't understand what you mean when say "can be unequal in general". What means "in general"?)